# Individual search filters for fields in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django-rest-framework will has a `SearchFilter` backend that will allow a single query against the searchable fields:

```
class OrganizationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    filter_fields = ('sector', 'industry', 'marketplace')
    search_fields = ('symbol',)
```

this way, when I query `...?search=AMZ` it will only return records with a non-sensitive match in the `symbol` field.

If I add another element into the `search_fields` tuple, it will look for this same search string in **both**.

Is there a way to define these search fields individually that will allow me to do something like:

`?search_symbol=AMZ&search_name=Good` so that it looks for objects that have `AMZ` in `symbol` field and `good` in `name` field?

Comment: What you want to do looks more like a filter than a search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you will need a custom filter backend extending the `rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter` class. Specifically in the `rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter` class there is a method `get_search_terms`:

```
    def get_search_terms(self, request):
        """
        Search terms are set by a ?search=... query parameter,
        and may be comma and/or whitespace delimited.
        """
        params = request.query_params.get(self.search_param, '')
        return params.replace(',', ' ').split()
```

We can override this method in our own `CustomSearchFilter` class to take control of how you specify the search terms within the url, for example:

```
class CustomSearchFilter(SearchFilter):
    search_field_prefix = "search_"

    def get_search_terms(self, request):
        # get search fields from the class
        search_fields = getattr(request.resolver_match.func.view_class, 'search_fields', list())

        params = []

        # iterate over each query paramater in the url
        for query_param in request.query_params:

            # check if query paramater is a search paramater
            if query_param.startswith(CustomSearchFilter.search_field_prefix):

                # extrapolate the field name while handling cases where <CustomSearchFilter.search_field_prefix> is in the field name
                field = CustomSearchFilter.search_field_prefix.join(
                    query_param.split(CustomSearchFilter.search_field_prefix)[1:]
                )

                # only apply search filter for fields that are in the views search_fields
                if field in search_fields:
                    params.append(request.query_params.get(query_param, ''))

        return params
```

Now replace the `filters.SearchFilter` with your new `CustomSearchFilter` in your views `filter_backends`.

Hope this helps, I've written this without testing the code myself so let me know how you go!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using `django-filter` instead. Might make your life easier.

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html